# Регулярные выражение: Как разрешить ввод только цифр и букв, остальные символы удалять?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу запретить ввод символов не соответствующих регулярному выражению:

```
/^[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Т. е. сразу удалять недопустимые символы:

```
$(document).on('keyup','.searchsport',function(){

});
```

Comment: Знак каретки не должен стоять внутри квадратных скобок?

Comment: @user1056837, нет, не должен

Comment: посмотри лучше в сторону [атрибута pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern), а не яваскрипта

Comment: @Grundy, если память мне не изменяет, то вводить можно что угодно, валидация произойдёт только при отправке, что весьма **не** гуд.

Comment: @Other, в принципе валидация сразу срабатывает, и если не ошибаюсь в css даже можно стиль invalid прописать. Но да, ввод в данном случае может и не отменять, зависит от реализации в браузере

Comment: @Grundy, только что хром проверил. Только при отправке формы табличка возникает. А если учесть что формы - уже далеко не единственная панацея (AJAX рулит!), то паттерн не то, что нужно. Лис только подсвечивает ошибку, но вводи что хочешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохранять текущее значение input'а, считая его заведомо правильным. По событию изменения (HTML5 событие `input`) - будь то ввод с клавиатуры или copy-paste, новое содержание input'а проверяется на наличие символов помимо разрешённых.

Если нелегальные символы найдены – ставим предыдущее, законное значение input'а. А если всё в порядке – запоминаем поступившее новое правильное значение.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('in-txt')
  ,value = input.value;

input.addEventListener('input', onInput);

function onInput(e){
  var newValue = e.target.value;
  if( newValue.match(/[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9]/g)) {
     input.value = value;
     return;
  }
  value = newValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in-txt">
```

Отдельно рассмотрите вариант, когда в поле copy-paste'ом вставляют сразу много букв. В предложенном коде всё будет отвергнуто, будто ничего и не вставляли. Возможно, вы захотите поступить иначе: отфильтровать все незаконные символы и вставить оставшиеся.

При вводе нелегального символа в середину строки курсор переедет в конец строки, а выделение текста, если было, сбросится. Можно и этот момент обработать, но это уже за рамками данного вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Обновил ответ.

Добавил обработку вставки, нажатие запрещенных клавиш не переводит каретку в конец строки. Нажатие клавиш стрелок, tab, home, end не игнорируются. Проверил в хроме, возможно потребуются изменения для других браузеров.

Если найдете проблему, напишите, постараюсь исправить.
Ссылка на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqcxr67q/)

```
var allowedRegex = /^[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
var allowedCharRegex = /[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9]/;

$('input').on('paste', function (e) {
    // handle only copy paste here
    // get clipboard text
    var newValue = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');

    // if new value is incorrect then stop event
    if (!allowedRegex.test(newValue)) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});

$('input').keypress(function(e) {
    // check input character
    return allowedCharRegex.test(e.key);
});
```

Comment: отвратительный пример: попробуй стрелочками переместить курсор хотя бы на одну позицию влево, ну и для регулярки в данном случае вместо функции вторым параметром понятнее использовать просто пустую строку `.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'')`

Comment: Вопрос был как запретить вводить символы, про остальную логику не спрашивали

Comment: ну и еще стоит добавить, что при вводе символа в любое место - курсор будет передвинут в конец