# Ввод только букв, а не цифр

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = go;

function go() {
  let x = document.getElementById("in").value;
  let z = document.getElementById("out");

  if (x) {
    z.innerHTML = `Привет ${x}, хорошего дня!`;
  } else {
    alert("введите имя");
  }
}
```

```html
<p><input type="text" id="in"> Введите ваше имя</p>
<p id="out"></p>
<button id="btn">enter</button>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как задать значение, чтоб в *input* вводились только буквы, но не цифры ;(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/556333/256824

Comment: не очень так то понятно.... я только начинаю учить js и jqury не знаю ((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно проверять нажатую кнопку через событие `keydown` event.key — если оно будет содержать число - `return` прерывает выполнение функции, а `event.preventDefault()` отключает дефолтное поведение события (символ не печатается).

**UPD**: *А что делать, если значение вставляется из буфера обмена...* (c) Stepan Kasyanenko

→ При печати, сперва срабатывает событие `keydown`, потом `keyup`, потом `input`. Первые 2 работают только при нажатии кнопок, а input - при любом изменении значения поля, в том числе и через копипаст. Поэтому дело дойдет до инпута только при вставке иным способом, кроме ручной печати.

```js
let jin = document.getElementById("in");
let jout = document.getElementById("out");
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

jin.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  if( e.key.match(/[0-9]/) ) return e.preventDefault();
}); // Будет перехватывать все числа при ручном вводе. 
// Тажке нужна, чтобы replace не сбрасывал каретку, срабатывая каждый раз.

jin.addEventListener('input', function(e){
  // На случай, если умудрились ввести через копипаст или авто-дополнение.
  jin.value = jin.value.replace(/[0-9]/g, "");
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let val = jin.value;
  if ( val ) {
    jout.textContent = `Привет ${val}, хорошего дня!`;
  } else {
    alert("введите имя");
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="in" placeholder="Ваше Имя">
<button id="btn">Enter</button>
<p id="out"></p>
```

Для on-событий вместо preventDefault eсть `return false;`

P.s. внутри всех событий есть объект event, который содержит кучу информации про событие:

```js
elem.addEventListener('click', function(bubu){
  console.log( event ); // В консоли браузера будет удобнее смотреть, чем здесь.
  
  // console.log( bubu ); — то же самое.
  // Если у функции указан аргумент - он тоже начинает ссылаться на объект event
  // Часто в качестве аргумента указывают букву 'e'
});
```

```html
<button id="elem">Elem</button>
```

Comment: А что делать, если значение вставляется из буфера обмена, вставляется через drag&drop или идет автозаполнение на мобильном?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Упс. Тогда аффтару стоит принять соседний ответ)

Comment: Соседний ответ тоже не универсальный - первый и третий варианты - прыгает каретка в конец инпута. Второй вариант лучше всего, но не совсем то - не запрещает цифры, а показывает предупреждение.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Поправил баг с кареткой. Второй вариант здесь для полноты, может ТС-у он понравится.

Comment: @BuzzardDoc отлично получилось! ИМХО - второй вариант самый лучший. Разве вам бы еще поправить регулярное выражение - добавить `g` модификатор. Иначе при вставке *123*  строки `replace` заменит только один символ.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Ах да, совсем про него забыл. Спасибо что напомнили. Добавил.

Answer (score 3):

### #1

Вы можете использовать событие `oninput` и регулярное выражение:

```html
<p><input type="text" id="in" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'');"> Введите ваше имя</p>
<p id="out"></p>
<button id="btn">enter</button>
```

UPD: Вариант с фиксом перескачивающей каретки:

```html
<p><input type="text" id="in" oninput="if(/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(this.value)){let Selection = this.selectionStart-1;this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'');this.setSelectionRange(Selection, Selection);}"> Введите ваше имя</p>
<p id="out"></p>
<button id="btn">enter</button>
```

---

### #2

Так же можно использовать атрибут `pattern` если Вы работаете на `HTML5`:

```css
input:invalid {
    border-color: #C72D34;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p><input type="text" id="in" style='outline:none;' pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"/> Введите ваше имя</p>
  <p id="out"></p>
  <button id="btn">enter</button>
</form>
```

---

### #3

Если вы работаете с `jQuery` можно использовать его:

```js
$("#in").on("input", function(){
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="text" id="in"> Введите ваше имя</p>
<p id="out"></p>
<button id="btn">enter</button>
```

UPD: Вариант с фиксом перескачивающей каретки:

```js
$("#in").on("input", function(){
    if(/[^a-zA-Z]/.test($(this).val())){
        let Selection = this.selectionStart-1;
        $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'') );
        this.setSelectionRange(Selection, Selection)
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="text" id="in"> Введите ваше имя</p>
<p id="out"></p>
<button id="btn">enter</button>
```

Измените `[^a-zA-Z]` на `[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-яЁё]` если хотите разрешить русские буквы.

Так же советую ознакомится с [этим гайдом](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) по регулярным выражениям.